# SparkJava Dataset insert into ClickHouse Table could not pass the too many parts exception

Tags: java, apache-spark, clickhouse

I get dataset from Kafka source with spark/java, but too many parts occur when I insert the dataset into clickhouseTable, I touch an XML file in /etc/clickhouse-server/config.d/merge_tree.xml, and paste the content copied from other solutions on the internet, here are the follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<yandex>
  <merge_tree>
    <old_parts_lifetime>30</old_parts_lifetime>
    <parts_to_delay_insert>150</parts_to_delay_insert>
    <parts_to_throw_insert>900</parts_to_throw_insert>
    <max_delay_to_insert>5</max_delay_to_insert>
  </merge_tree>
</yandex>
```

and I also add the tags in user.xml:

```
<profiles>
  ...
  <default>
     <max_partitions_per_insert_block>10000</max_partitions_per_insert_block>
  </defualt>
  ...
</profiles>
```

and my spark codes are:

```
 dataset.repartition(1).write().mode(SAVEMODE.APPEND)
        .option("batchsize",""10000")
        .option("isolationLevel","NONE")
        .option("numPartitions","1")
        .option("driver",driver)
        .jdbc(url,tableName,properties).
```

However, too many exceptions still occur in the spark JDBC stage, I am really confused and wish for your help. Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Why do you need this <max_partitions_per_insert_block>10000 ?

Comment: Please ignore it, I just have a try with this tag with referring to [link](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/operations/settings/query-complexity/) , and it does not work, but my another project with java.sql.Connection in spark rdd's foreachPartition method can finish insertion into ClickHouse. @DennyCrane

Answer (score 0):

Increase the executor memory and batchsize

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe transactions support could help?
Look detail on
https://github.com/ClickHouse/clickhouse-jdbc/pull/1008#issuecomment-1303964814

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Please [edit] the answer with all relevant information. Make sure to use your own words, [answers comprised entirely of a quote (sourced or not) will often be deleted since they do not contain any original content.](/help/referencing).